# How is std::fstream with both in and out supposed to work?

Tags: c++, io, fstream

I've just started wondering - how is actually `std::fstream` opened with both `std::ios::in` and `std::ios::out` actually supposed to work? What should it do? Write something to (for example) an empty file, then read... what? Just written value? Where would the file "pointer"/"cursor" be? Maybe the answer's already out there but I just couldn't have found it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## What is `std::fstream`?

`std::fstream` is a bidirectional file stream class. That is, it provides an interface for both input and output for files. It is commonly used when a user needs to read from and write to the same external sequence.

When instantiating a bidirectional file stream (unlike `std::ofstream` or `std::ifstream`), the openmodes `ios_base::in` and `ios_base::out` are specified *by default*. This means that this:

```
std::fstream f("test.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
```

is the same as

```
std::fstream f("test.txt");
```

One would specify both options if they needed to also add some non-default openmodes such as `trunc`, `ate`, `app`, or `binary`. The `ios_base::trunc` openmode is needed if you intend to *create* a new file for bidirectional I/O, because the `ios_base::in` openmode disables the creation of a new file.

## Bidirectional I/O

Bidirectional I/O is the utilization of a bidirectional stream for both input and output. In IOStreams, the standard streams maintain their character sequences in a buffer where it serves as a source or sink for data. For output streams, there is a "put" area (the buffer that holds characters for output). Likewise, for input streams, there is the "get" area.

In the case of `std::fstream` (a class for both input *and* output), it holds a joint file buffer representing both the get and put area respectively. The position indicator that marks the current position in the file is affected by both input *and* output operations. As such, in order to perform I/O correctly on a bidirectional stream, there are certain rules you must follow:

- When you perform a read after a write or vice-versa, the stream should be repositioned back.
- If an input operation hit the end-of-file, performing a write directly thereafter is fine.

This only refers to `std::fstream`. The above rules are not needed for `std::stringstream`.

I hope these answer your questions. If you have any more, you can just ask in the comments.