# c++ - binary files and how can do action on them (print the file)

Tags: c++, file

I write to a file but when I try to read from the file I get an infinite loop

When I work with a regular file I can print this shape but with no binary file. why?
And when I want to do actions on a sample binary file how do I do this if I can not go over the file with a loop?
I would be happy to explain thank you.

main.cpp:

```
string text;
//getline(cin, text);

text = "3.14159#12#Good Luck!# - 2.718";

char ch2;
fstream outBinary1;// output to text 
outBinary1.open("binary1.txt", ios::binary | ios::out);

const char *temp = text.c_str();
outBinary1.write(temp, text.length());

outBinary1.get(ch2);// first char in text

while (!outBinary1.eof()){
    cout << ch2 ;
    outBinary1.get(ch2);
}

outBinary1.close();
```

Comment: You are not supposed to read from file opened for writing.

Comment: Step through this with a debugger and watch what's happening. It will almost certainly be more educational than a written answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is hard to understand what you want to establish and have problems with, but I will give it a try.

If you want to read from the file you have to specify `ios::in`additionally.

Supposed you want to read from the beginning of the file (after writing), you have to reposition the stream first (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288562/how-is-stdfstream-with-both-in-and-out-supposed-to-work)). Therefore [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) can be used.

What you want may look like that:

```
string text;
//getline(cin, text);

text = "3.14159#12#Good Luck!# - 2.718";

char ch2;
// You may want to rename this
fstream outBinary1;// output to text
outBinary1.open("binary1.txt", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::in);

const char *temp = text.c_str();
outBinary1.write(temp, text.length());

outBinary1.seekg(0, outBinary1.beg); // only if you want to read from the beginning

outBinary1.get(ch2);// first char in text

while (!outBinary1.eof()){
    cout << ch2 ;
    outBinary1.get(ch2);
}

outBinary1.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void f(){
const string text("3.14159#12#Good Luck!# - 2.718");
fstream outBinary1;
outBinary1.open("binary1.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);

outBinary1.write(text.c_str(), text.length());

outBinary1.seekg (0, outBinary1.beg);

char ch2;
outBinary1.get(ch2);// first char in text
while (outBinary1){
    cout << ch2 ;
    outBinary1.get(ch2);
}

outBinary1.close();
}

int main(int, char**){
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

The two lines to change are

```
outBinary1.open("binary1.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
outBinary1.seekg (0, outBinary1.beg);
```

The first one to force the file to be created and the second one to move the fp back to start. Compiled with g++ and no switches